# Android Photo Gallery does not return correct Uri from data in OnActivityResult

Tags: java, android, android-intent, gallery

I am using android studio. I tried to process a photo that is in the gallery.

I call `startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_Load);`

In protected `void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)`

the `Uri` returns from `data.getData()` is not correct. like

> content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fimages%2Fmedia%2F128/ORIGINAL/NONE/1980269994

That has no image name.

How to get around it? Thanks.

Comment: Add your `Intent` in question .

Answer (score 0):

If You are Using

```
requirdUri = Uri.fromFile(theSrcPath);
```

Your Device Is Above Nauget you Should use this code from get URI from Camera and Gallery

you Should Create Provider to user below Method.
for This You Have To Create One Folder inside

> res - > Xml --> and Add One File Named File_path_public.xml.
>   **Note : You Can Choose Any File Name**

and Inside That File Put Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

-<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<external-path path="." name="external_files"/>

</paths>
```

And In Your Manifest File Inside Application Tag Create One Provider Like:

```
<!-- this is For Access External file Storage -->
<provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="com.example.appName.provider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/file_paths_public" />
</provider>
```

and Then Create This Function Below:

```
public static Uri getUriFromFile(Context theCtx, File theSrcPath) {
        Uri requirdUri = null;

        // Above Compile SDKversion: 25 -- Uri.fromFile Not working
        // So we have to use Provider
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            requirdUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(theCtx,
                    theCtx.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + CommonUtils.PROVIDER_FILE_EXTENSION,
                    theSrcPath);
        } else {
            requirdUri = Uri.fromFile(theSrcPath);
        }

        return requirdUri;
    }
```

Note That You Should Have Permission For External Storage In Manifest.

Comment: Thank you for the helping. I have found out a way to get the file name, but I don't know the path. therefore I have no idea about the value that pass into fromFile().

Comment: @psbookmark Have you figured this out? I'm having the same issue. I'm unable to get the correct Uri for a file which I wanna upload to some server.

Answer (score 0):

If you want image name then you should create a file then get a name from that.for example:

```
File f = new File(uri.getPath());
String imageName = f.getName();
```